# Vhosts dont work on Mac Apache environment

Tags: php, mysql, macos, apache

I'm not sure exactly what could have happened. Everything was functioning correctly, until I added (with homebrew) this https://github.com/virtualhost/virtualhost.sh
. Thinking that it would help me make vhosts, but alas something is screwy and I can no longer access my sites with vhosts.

I run /usr/bin/httpd -S and it returns this

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server localhost (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:23)
     port 80 namevhost localhost (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:23)
     port 80 namevhost andydennybanjos.dev (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:28)
             alias www.andydennybanjos.dev
             ServerRoot: "/usr"
             Main DocumentRoot: "/Users/Krsna/Sites"
             Main ErrorLog: "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"
             Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
     Mutex proxy: using_defaults
     Mutex default: dir="/private/var/run/" mechanism=default
     Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
     PidFile: "/private/var/run/httpd.pid"
     Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
     Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
     User: name="Krsna" id=501 not_used
     Group: name="staff" id=20 not_used
```

Anyone got any ideas of things I can try or look for? I just ditched MAMP Pro to go with the native version of PHP, MySQL, and Apache. It's been pretty fun learning new terminal stuff, but I'm stumped now! Wish I hadn't tried to mess with anything once I got it all working how I liked it to, but ya live and learn.